# How can I sort numbers in a string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id   String
1    345 -456 -13  879
2    158 -926 -81  249 35 -4 -53  9
3    945 -506 -103
```

I want to sort it in desending order like this

```
id   String
1    879 345 -13 -457
2    249 158 35 9 -4 -53 -81 -926
3    945 -103 -506
```

I tried this:

`df['string'] = df['string'].str.split(' ').map(lambda x: ' '.join(sorted(x)))`

The above function do some kind of sorting but not the way I want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First is necessary convert values to integers, sorting and then convert to strings back:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x), reverse=True)))
#another solution
#f = lambda x: ' '.join(str(z) for z in sorted((int(y) for y in x), reverse=True))
df['string'] = df['string'].str.split().map(f)
print (df)
   id                        string
0   1              879 345 -13 -456
1   2  249 158 35 9 -4 -53 -81 -926
2   3                 945 -103 -506
```

Or:

```
f = lambda x: ' '.join(map(str, sorted(map(int, x.split()), reverse=True)))
df['string'] = df['string'].map(f)
```

Comment: Hey, I am getting this error: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '345'.` The dtype of df['string'] is `object`

Comment: @johndoe - For me working nice, it seems some data related problem, what is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: Here is the output (It is a bit different from the above df, because it was just sample).

Comment: `{'string': {0: '-4200.0 -135400.0 -148000.0 -58500.00000000001 -2800.0 -26899.999999999996 -51400.0 -33800.0 -18600.0 -65900.0 -23499.999999999996', 1: '-15200.0 -148000.0 -67700.0 -26000.0 -27300.0 -28599.999999999996 -25799.999999999996 -108199.99999999999 -19900.0 -31900.0 -89400.0 -63300.0', 2: '-31400.0 -12800.0 -1200.0', 3: '-32700.000000000004 -15999.999999999998 -18300.0 -200.0 -7000.0 -99.99999999999999', 4: '0.0 -8100.0 -4399.999999999999'}}`

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe `pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'` will help to convert object into int?

Comment: My bad, My original text was in float. I fixed it, and works perfectly. Thanks